# Есть ли ошибка здесь?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нет ли стилистической ошибки в данном примере: "Я не жду позитивный исход, что вернёт всё на прежний лад"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я не жду позитивный исход, что вернёт всё на прежний лад.*

Всё здесь не так: неясный смысл, смешение стилей, неверный падеж.

Да и редактировать это предложение сложно, так как совершенно неясен контекст и коммуникативная ситуация (другими словами, что там случилось с нашим героем, какие у него проблемы).

Один из вариантов редактирования может выглядеть так (если ситуация понята верно):

***Я не жду благоприятных перемен, которые вернули бы всё на прежний лад.***

Пояснение:

1) Выбор лексики должен быть оправданным, канцелярские выражения не всегда уместны.

2) Падеж родительный, сравним: жду поезда (вообще) и жду поезд с конкретным номером.

3) Желание лучше выразить глаголом в сослагательном наклонении.

4) Союзное слово ЧТО не всегда может заменить союзное слов КОТОРЫЙ.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо грамматических ошибок, здесь есть ошибка *логическая*: "позитивный исход" фигурирует как *причина* возвращения к прежнему порядку, в то время как его *содержание* заключается в таком возвращении:

> Я жду позитивного исхода - того, что всё *пойдёт на лад* (*вернётся к
>   прежнему порядку*).

Answer (score 0):

Падеж "*позитивный исход*" может быть, если уже точно известно, какой именно исход. Но это вряд ли. Лучше родительный падеж.

Разве может исход вернуть что-то? Нет. Это не субъект, который вершит действия. Скорее, в исходе может что-то вернуться.

Лучше так:
*Я не жду позитивного исхода, в котором всё вернётся на прежний лад.*